# Can you match words without matching parts of words with the same spelling?

Tags: regex, ruby

I was wondering if there was a way to replace independent words in a string without changing parts of words with the same spelling.  An example is to convert:

```
a = "hey how is the heyday"
```

into:

```
"wrong how is the heyday"
```

Is there a way to do this?

This will not work:

```
a.gsub! "hey", "wrong"
# => "wrong how is the wrongday"
```

Comment: Just change `"hey"` to `/\bhey\b/` in `a.gsub! "hey", "wrong"`. `/\bhey\b/` is a regular expression `\b` is called a "word break". It requires `"hey"` to not be immediately preceded or followed by a "word" character (a letter, digit or underscore). Don't be surprised if your question is closed because it's a duplicate, as a form of it has been asked many times.

Comment: Bless ya mate you have done more then you could know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have posted in comments, one way you can do this is with a regular expression in your gsub

```
  a = "hey how is the heyday"
  a.gsub(/hey\b/,'wrong')
```

The regex here is looking for the word `hey` with a word boundary.
But also note than when you use `gsub!` you modify the variable you were calling it on.  If you want to assign a new variable the result, use `gsub` alone without a bang.